# How to Select a Folder and Its Subfolders to Store Images in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, directory, electron, subdirectory, quasar-framework

I'm using Vue.js, and Quasar. I want to allow the user to select a folder, including its subfolders, and store all images in a variable. I only want to display them later, not upload them.

I've tried using the Quasar q-uploader, but it requires selecting images individually and doesn't allow choosing an entire folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, you may need to implement this yourself, use [webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)